# Calculus proof: $0=1$ What is my mistake?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, fake-proofs

The quotient rule states that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{{g(x)}^2}=\frac{f'(x)}{g(x)}-\frac{f(x)g'(x)}{{g(x)}^2}$$
Integrating tells us that
$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\int\frac{f'(x)}{g(x)}dx-\int\frac{f(x)g'(x)}{{g(x)}^2}dx$$
If I let $f(x)=g(x)$,this gives us:
$$\frac{f(x)}{f(x)}=\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx-\int\frac{f(x)f'(x)}{{f(x)}^2}dx=\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx-\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx$$
Simplifying both sides:
$$1=0$$
Where have I erred? Where and what is my mistake? Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, straight ahead letting $f=g$ means you're differentiating $1$ so you get $0$,
but let's go through this again:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{f'(x)f(x)-f(x)f'(x)}{{f(x)}^2}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$
$$\implies 1= \int(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}) dx=\int0 \ dx=C$$
So no contradiction.

Update: you did it in another way:
$$ 1= \int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx-\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx$$
Now let $y=f(x)$, we get 
$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx= \int \frac{1}{y}dy=\ln(y)+C=\ln(f(x))+C$$
So 
$$1=\ln(f(x))+C_1 - (\ln(f(x))+C_2)=C_1-C_2$$
again, no contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't $\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx-\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx$ for all cases?

Comment: @A-levelStudent
Yes. See my update to this answer, you'll understand what went down in both the right and the left hand sides

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah yes, right, sorry. It wouldn't matter in proving the point anyways :D

Answer (score 3):

When you integrated both sides, you left out the constant.

Answer (score 2):

When integrating, you will still get a constant term. In this case the constant term is 1

Answer (score 2):

If $ g $ and $ h $ are both differentiable at an intervall $ I $ satisfying

$$(\forall x\in I)\;\;\;  \frac{d}{dx}g(x)=\frac{d}{dx}h(x)$$

THEN, there exists a Constant $ C $ such that
$$(\forall x\in I)\;\; g(x)=h(x)+C$$

with $C=g(a)-h(a)$ for any $ a\in I$.

in your case, $g(x)=1$ and $h(x)=0$.

Comment: Thanks.What does the bracketed part in the second line mean?

Comment: @A-levelStudent To make propositions clearer and more precise. for example $P\implies Q and R$ is not like $(P\implies Q)  and R$.